# Bcrypt Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, bcrypt

i have this code on my controller (codeigniter)

this is my `login` method

```
function login()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        echo $post['pass_user'];
        if(!empty($post))
        {
            $this->db->where('name_user',$post['name_user']);
            $data = $this->db->get('tb_user')->result_array();
            if(empty($data))
            {
                echo "Tidak ada username";
            }
            else
            {
                if(password_verify($post['pass_user'] , $data['pass_user']))
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data['name_user'], $data['lvl_user']);
                    echo "password same";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "password not same";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

and i have value `$2y$10$uutShFadO9zEvLMLiHIwcem5hMeFHIG9UQtXeCtKs8ClVJGWZgwSy` for my `pass_user` in my database.

But in result i get 'password not same'. How to solve this ?

Comment: You cannot decrypt a password stored with bcrypt. That's the whole point of using a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: if $2y$10$uutShFadO9zEvLMLiHIwcem5hMeFHIG9UQtXeCtKs8ClVJGWZgwSy is the crypted value of say "abcd1234" and its not working then check for white spaced while inserting... if you forgot the actual password then look for how to decrypt password, they will show you alternative to change your pass because decrypt is not possible as Sachina Aghera mentioned it above.

Comment: also do echo $post['pass_user'] , $data['pass_user'] , if you dont get value here then debug previous scope. you might not be getting the data resulting in flow to go in else condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

*You are returning multidimensional data using this `result_array();` you have to use it with key  in `password_verify` method like this `$data[0]['pass_user']`, this will work if you have only single row, So better you should return single array data by using `row_array();`*

Replace this line of code

```
$data = $this->db->get('tb_user')->result_array();
```

with this

```
$data = $this->db->get('tb_user')->row_array();
```

The whole code

```
    function login()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        echo $post['pass_user'];
        if(!empty($post))
        {
            $this->db->where('name_user',$post['name_user']);

            //$data = $this->db->get('tb_user')->result_array();

            $data = $this->db->get('tb_user')->row_array();
            if(empty($data))
            {
                echo "Tidak ada username";
            }
            else
            {
                if(password_verify($post['pass_user'] , $data['pass_user']))
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data['name_user'], $data['lvl_user']);
                    echo "password same";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "password not same";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check my answer as green